# Passing Python variables as an arguments to a perl script

Tags: python, django, perl

I have a Django project where one of the Python functions uses a Perl script, and I am passing Python variables as arguments.

But instead of using the values of the Python variables it is passing the variable names.

How can I pass these variables generically to a Perl script?

```
log output is as follows:
('Isource username is %s ', u'sudhb')
('Isource password is %s ', u'123456')
(' Command is %s ', ['flexiserver/build/svnenv.sh', '-j', 'svntasktag.pl -u i_uname -a i_passw ss_fvnteste'])
```

#### Python code

```
i_uname = request.POST.get('uname')
i_passw = request.POST.get('ispsw')

args_str1 = "flexiserver/build/svnenv.sh -j 'svntasktag.pl -u " + i_uname + " -a " + i_passw + " -c \"" + i_desc + "\" ss_fvnteste'"
args1     = shlex.split(args_str2)
pi = subprocess.Popen(args1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout = pi.communicate()
```

Comment: Hope you have missed to give the compiler `perl` before the filename ex: `perl svntasktag.pl `

Comment: but in the log i am not getting the values of the variables. it is directly replacing variable names. once if i get values then only we can able to run the perl script right? Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: In the log the command is showing as below:                                                    (' Command is %s ', ['f\x00\x00\x00l\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00x\x00\x00\x00i\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00r\x00\x00\x00v\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00r\x00\x00\x00/\x00\x00\x00b\x00\x00\x00u\x00\x00\x00i\x00\x00\x00l

Comment: It's much better to pass the command line as a list, instead of a string. Then it doesn't go through the shell, so you don't have to worry about quoting and escaping.

Comment: can you give me an example how to do that ? I am new to django and python it would be really helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved by using replace in python.
I replaced back slash as follows

```
args_str1 = "flexiserver/build/svnenv.sh -j 'svntasktag_pdash.pl -u " + i_uname + " -a " + i_passw + " -c \"" + i_desc + "\" ss_fvnteste'"

            args2 = str(args_str1).replace("\\","")
```

This worked for me